# CharacterController's collider doesn't collide with BoxCollider2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I have a player and a platform on my scene. The scene is in 2D.

Here are *platform's* components:

[image]

Here are *player's* components:

[[image]]

To move the player - I use **SimpleMove()** method:

```
CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 3.0F;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        Vector2 movementVector = new Vector2(movement, 0f);

        controller.SimpleMove(movementVector * speed);
    }
```

Comment: Other than you don’t detail any question in your text. Going by the title. There doesn’t look to be any rigidbody or collider on your player. So no. It wont

Comment: In 3D you actually don't need rigidbody nor collider to be attached to object if it has character controller - that's sufficient bundle to make the player collisions happen. Problem here is mixing character controller which is intended for 3D with 2D colliders, nor really missing RB or collider, which technically is the case, but in different sense :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you're trying to achieve will not work as expected. Character Controller is actually intended for 3D and you're expecting it to collide with 2D colliders that works differently and most importantly are not compatible

Character Controller brings 3D capsule collider to it's object - see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html

You may try to experiment with adding some 2D collider and eventually also RigiBody2D to your object. Character Controller is intended also for cases without using physics (except collisions), so if that's the case also for your 2D game, creating own character controller could be quite straight forward option as well